Bee in the Bonnet questioners
What is/should be the policy for "bee in the bonnet" questioners?
eg.

Polcott who is very personally offended by Mr. Gödel
Thinkingman and his antiGod pro physicalist 100s of questions
Circle Etymology earlier Vitalie Ghelbert IIRC, who is very personally offended by zero. This recent question prompted this meta question
Arnold tenth(?) repeat on solipsism
Boltstorm, all of whose questions amount to I want naive realism to be philosophically sound; and I'll bawl if that doesn't fly


I believe you've neglected the user who keeps asking "can one have a justified belief in X, or Y, or Z, or W, or .....?". Yes, at least they don't say "god" explicitly every time, but it sure feels like they mean "god", and 90% of the time it's a language issue about "justification", or "belief".

Youre welcome to edit that into my question @JonathanZ. [We have community wiki answers but not questions]. Obviously the point is not to chronicle the varieties of the bees but how to contain them (if any)... You may well like the stings and the honey!!

I'm used to the math.se standards, where we don't do more than minor corrections of what someone else has said. And I really don't want to risk to be seen as putting words in someone else's mouth - especially as things are a bit more opinion based here. But please feel free to take whatever part of my comment you feel appropriate and add it to your question!

@JonathanZ The problem with that questioner is different. Its often nothing to do with Justified Belief but its always thinly disguised Christian proselytism under quite well argued philosophy (theology). Check my older meta questions on the place of theology out here one, two. Ver broadly, the problem I am talking of is more of trolling. That is closer to spamming

Me, I don't see such a great difference, but since you do, let's leave that example out of your question, so as to keep the scope smaller, and increase the chance of getting useful decisions here.

I think the user asking about Justified Belief has backed out of the site. I entertained his questions but kept asking, "are you finding what you are looking for? Maybe asking in a place where results are unlikely to help you?"

Have you ever considered that we might be living in a simulation? I mean, some guy suggested it 20 years ago so we have to keep it in mind... But then, perhaps the Hindu view basically says that anyhow :-)

My personal take is quite simple: The same as with anyone else!
If anything, the best take should be to more rigorously vote as duplicate all the questions that guise the same idea in different words.

I appreciate your position Phil. Please excuse me though, for not using the VTC

Also note that the question is closed but is still being actively edited and hence bumped by the questioner. You can say I am adding to the disorder by adding to my answer. My defence is that I try to keep my edits close in time to the users bumps so the questioner is near the top of active questions any way whether i did it or not. Earlier I had a note there saying: This answer may be deleted along with parent question, to signal that in my opinion this was a deleteable quesion

Phil Klöcking says:

It cannot be stressed enough that most of these God-questions are posted by a small number of users and multiplied mainly through the fact that questions almost a 100% candidate for Hot Network Questions because everyone has so strong opinions about them.
I  cannot tell you how much I am fed up with the millionth variation of the ever same question trying to fish for popularity votes but here we are, discussing it again.

Scott Rowe says:

There seems to be a string of questions which just state the same underlying (basically unanswerable) question in different ways.

To Phil
A basic intuition of CS is that difficult problems are often easier solved in a more general form than their default formulation.
So

Add 78643909 to 364097542 seems hard

Its easy(er)

Write a program to add to decimal numbers

So perhaps you should concentrate on the general category of people stuck with bees in their bonnet rather than treat each of God, solipsism, snake-has-even-legs, Gödel-is-nonsense or whatever as a special case.
All these are fine and interesting for a while but beyond that the questioner needs to be told:

You have repeatedly and in different guises asked what you wanted to ask. We have answered as best as we could.  This is now not making progress. Please desist (from these questions).

To Scott
A(nother) intuition of the wizened CS-ist is the instinctive detection and unease with infinite loops/recursion.
It can be a surprise even after decades of experience to what extent the halting problem is as easy to state as it's impossible to solve.
If instead of focusing on "grounding" (title) you focus on:
String of questions which just state the same underlying (basically unanswerable) question in different ways
I believe the solution will be more within reach

Hi. I was hoping that getting people to ground their questions would have one of two results: 1. An answerable question 2. OP would realize it is unanswerable. I suspect that 99 times out of 100 it would be the second result, and we would have a sort of Disenchantment Machine which would take deluded lost souls in at one end, and turn out humble, sadder but more useful folks at the other. But, I'm pretty optimistic about the efficacy of my variety of skeptical sarcastic pessimism. I could be wrong.
